# Using the Describe API, how can I tell whether a given Custom Setting is of list or hierarchy type?

Tags: apex, customsetting

I'm using `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` to walk through the list of sObjects in the system. The `DescribeSobjectResult` offers `isCustomSetting()`, which allows me to tell which objects are custom settings. What I haven't been able to determine is which of those custom settings are hierarchy and which are lists. Both have a `SetupOwnerId` field, although I don't believe it's meaningful for list settings.

Is there any way to tell the two object types apart with the API?

Comment: I've found a workaround for this issue. While the schemata of the Hierarchy and List custom settings are identical, Salesforce will raise a required field exception on insert if the Name field is null on a list setting but not a hierarchy setting. Similarly, a Field Integrity Exception is raised if the SetupOwnerId field is populated on a list setting, but not a hierarchy setting.

Comment: ... and a further, better workaround: the Name field is nillable (`isNillable()` returns true in its field describe) for Hierarchy settings only. It's required for List settings.

Comment: WoW! 3 years and still there is no better solution to this! Thanks David for saving my day.

Answer (score 5):

I just did a `System.debug(xxx__c.SObjectType.getDescribe())` on a list custom setting an a hierarchical one and both output:

```
isAccessible=true;
isCreateable=true;
isCustom=true;
isCustomSetting=true;
isDeletable=true;
isDeprecatedAndHidden=false;
isFeedEnabled=false;
isMergeable=false;
isMruEnabled=false;
isQueryable=true;
isSearchable=true;
isUndeletable=true;
isUpdateable=true;
```

so I don't think there is anything that distinguishes them in the describe API. You are probably stuck with finding differences by using the [methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm) or by querying or by updating.

Comment: Hi Keith, can you say more about what you mean by distinguishing them using the methods, queries, or updates? I haven't for the life of me been able to figure out how to do that given an Sobject token or name, since the uniquely hierarchy methods are static.